# Git failed with a fatal error - could not read Username terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, github

What might be the problem with my local git ?
I was able to pull just before 5 minutes, and all of the sudden when I tried to pull again, it asked me to enter user/psw. I did that, but it gave me this error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I am able to login in github.com, but locally it keeps asking me user/password and gives me the above error.

*Note: When using github for desktop it's all okay.*

Answer (score 2):

You, or some software you are using, has set:

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0
```

or:

```
GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=false
```

in your environment.  Stop doing that, or make the software stop doing that.  (See also [go get results in 'terminal prompts disabled' error for github private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32232655/1256452) and [How do I disable credential prompting for git clone in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46440000/1256452))

Alternatively, set up your credential manager<sup>1</sup> to store or cache the user name and password.  Be careful with this, especially because many of these store passwords insecurely (e.g., in cleartext).

Alternatively, use `ssh` instead of `https`.  While https authentication requires that Git obtain a user name and password from a credential manager, ssh authentication does not.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git itself doesn't do any authentication.  Instead, it fobs this off on other programs or libraries.  To use https authentication, Git has to invoke library routines, for which it needs a user name and password; to obtain the user name and password, Git invokes a separate *credential manager*.  There are many credential managers, and they are both OS- and user-dependent, so that you can choose a credential manager that works only on your Mac, or one that works only on your Windows system.  Git also comes with some simple-and-dumb credential managers that just store the user name and password in a file, or in some temporary storage.